# Who was wearing the perfume in the episode Syzygy of X-Files

Tags: the-x-files

During this episode in Season 3, Mulder mentions that someone is wearing his favourite perfume. He checks Scully, and she doesn't appear to be wearing it. Later, he checks the detective, but she is also not wearing it. The only other people in the room were the doctor and one of the 'witches'.

I took it that it was the doctor with the perfume, but it seems confusing (even by X-Files standards!) that it wasn't resolved. It seems like something that is irrelevant, but curiously important.

Is it ever stated inside or outside of the episode who was wearing the perfume?

Comment: I haven't found anything, even in the typed-up [commentary](https://web.archive.org/web/20111122021952/http://www.mitchpileggi.net/The_X-Files/Libby/Season-3-episodes.pdf) for the season.

Comment: In the previous scene, the pediatrician was wearing make-up and women's clothes (a robe and high heels). Apparently he had time to remove the lipstick and change into street clothes before the mob broke down his door or the authorities arrested him, but not enough time for a shower to wash off the scent. Notice that besides Mulder, the only other person in the frame when Fox mentions the perfume is the pediatrician.

Comment: That matches what I thought. I swear the doctor had a nervous face when Mulder said it. It seems to be a repeating theme throughout the rest of the episode though, with Mulder somehow trying to track it down and not caring about any other kind of 'stimulant'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the scene where Mulder detects the scent of his favorite perfume, there are only five people in the police station.

> SCENE 14  (At the precinct) WHITE: Let me get this straight, for the
>   record; you haven’t seen the bag in a year and you sold it at a garage
>   sale.
>
> GODFREY: To a young girl, one of the Roberts family. They live a few
>   doors down.
>
> WHITE: Why was it filled with bones and buried in the middle of a
>   field?
>
> GODFREY: I have no idea.
>
> WHITE: Well, the people of this town seem to think you do. Would you
>   be willing to take a lie detector test?
>
> GODFREY: Eh…
>
> (Scully enters.)
>
> SCULLY: You can go now Dr. Godfrey, I don’t think we’ll be needing you
>   any further. Your story checked out.
>
> GODFREY: Thank God. (Gets up and puts on jack, standing behind
>   Mulder.)
>
> SCULLY: The bones, turned out to be the skeletal remains not of an
>   infant, but of a beloved, fourteen year old [lasa apso], formerly
>   known as (holds out collar) Mr. Tippy.
>
> (Terri enters the room.)
>
> TERRI: Mr. Tippy…
>
> MULDER: This may not be any time to mention it, but someone is wearing
>   my favorite perfume.

We have Mulder, Detective White, Godfrey, Scully, and Terri.
Mulder obviously is not wearing the perfume himself. He determines that it is not Scully.

> MULDER: (Loses interest, starts sniffling the air, closing in around
>   Scully’s head.)
>
> SCULLY: I see no reason to pursue this case any further and not only
>   that, I find your conduct and comportment in this investigation not
>   just alarming, but highly objectionable. What are you doing?!
>
> MULDER: (slightly distracted.) Must be detective White…

He tries to determine whether Detective White is wearing the perfume:

> WHITE: (upset) If they’re not Satanists, who are they?
>
> (Mulder walks to her and embraces her comfortingly, then starts
>   sniffling her perfume.)
>
> WHITE: (pushing him away.) What are you doing?
>
> MULDER: Nothing.

Although there is no indication in the script that Mulder determines that Detective White was not wearing the perfume, the impression I got from the scene was that she was not. **However, it is possible that Detective White was the one wearing the perfume.**

The other possibilities are Terri and Godfrey. **As mentioned in the comments by @Dan Bron, Godfrey, who engages in occasional cross-dressing, is implied by the camera work to be the one who is wearing the perfume.** That said, we cannot definitely rule out the possibility that Terri is the one wearing it, or indeed that Detective White wasn't wearing it.